# How can I solve the font error for the story book?

Tags: reactjs, storybook, codekit

I can deploy my local environment with the story book, I do it with: npm run dev
When he shows me the story book he shows me the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AddFH.png)

I already cleared cache with: rm -rf node_modules
I did the npm install again
but I persist with the same error.

This happened to me because I changed the version, as the Story Book said that I should have done it, it was in the version.
7.6.16 and this didn't happen to me
I decided to go back to the version but I still have the error and currently I still have the same error in version 17

Comment: maybe the error is not from storybook, we can't decide unless you provide some related code. however, the error is saying that you are trying to access the property `font` in a specific `object` and that object is undefined, check if you are calling API and then accessing the `font` property in it.